# the folder does not have access to the server

Tags: java, server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPRYH.png)
The server should output text files from the folder to the client.
The program finds the folder, but there is no access. Please help me decide what to do!
The program works correctly on other computers
Access denied

server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Socket s = null;

        File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\uchik\\sonets");

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("\n" +
                    "FILE DOES NOT EXIST");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ("FILE FOUNDED");
        }


        try{
            Random rand = new Random();

            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
            s = server.accept();
            PrintStream ks = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
            FileReader fread = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bfread = new BufferedReader(fread);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while (bfread.ready())
            {
                list.add(bfread.readLine());
            }
            String m = list.get(rand.nextInt(50));
            ks.print(m);
            ks.flush();
            s.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println ("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtpha.png)

Comment: What is different about other computers? Can you post the full stack-trace of the error? Images are not as useful as text - remove them and replace them with their text contents.

Comment: In the beginning try to check if the files are accessible, if not ask the user to change permission to files or to run your program with a more privileged user.